# как перенести url в переменную?

Tags: python, парсер, requests, bs4

мне нужно чтобы случайный url(строка) из данного списка записывался в переменную

вот код:

```
import requests
from json import loads
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = requests.session()
s.headers.update({'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0'})

r = s.get('https://www.google.ru/search?q=кот&tbm=isch')

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

for i in range(0,10):
    for text in soup.findAll(attrs={'class': 'rg_meta notranslate'}):
        text = loads(text.text)
        print(text["ou"])
```

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Вы хотите использовать одну из полученных ссылок для повторного прогона?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для получения рандомной ссылки из полученных используйте модуль `numpy` `np`
Предварительно поместив результат в массив. 
Пример:

```
import requests
from json import loads
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import numpy as np

s = requests.session()
s.headers.update({'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0'})

r = s.get('https://www.google.ru/search?q=кот&tbm=isch')

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

arr = []
for i in range(0, 10):
    for text in soup.findAll(attrs={'class': 'rg_meta notranslate'}):
        text = loads(text.text)
        arr.append(text["ou"]) ## Помещаем ссылки в массив

randUrl = np.random.choice(arr, size=None, replace=True, p=None) ## получаем рандомное значение из массива
```

Answer (score 0):

Url ничем не отличается от набора символов, когда вы создаёте стринговую переменную

`target = 'https://www.google.ru/search?q=кот&tbm=isch...'`

Comment: Да, я понимаю что url это тоже string. Но я не понимаю как в данном случае взять из списка рандомную строку ( код брал из интернета ), возможно random.choice() но я не знаю как именно это сделать

Comment: @Qvint01 ранжомную строку чего? Картинки?